# How do I find the location where my grid is instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I began setting up my system by taking the Grid system supplied by Pack publishing (). This is how it's initialized:

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj is Point)
        {
            Point p = obj as Point;
            return this.X == p.X && this.Y == p.Y;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 6949;
            hash = hash * 7907 + X.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 7907 + Y.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "P(" + this.X + ", " + this.Y + ")";
    }
}

public enum CellType
{
    Empty,
    Road,
    Structure,
    SpecialStructure,
    None
}

public class Grid
{
    private CellType[,] _grid;
    private int _width;
    public int Width { get { return _width; } }
    private int _height;
    public int Height { get { return _height; } }

    private List<Point> _roadList = new List<Point>();
    private List<Point> _specialStructure = new List<Point>();
    private List<Point> _houseStructure = new List<Point>();

    public Grid(int width, int height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _grid = new CellType[width, height];
    }

public enum CellType
{
    Empty,
    Road,
    Structure,
    SpecialStructure,
    None
}

public class Grid
{
    private CellType[,] _grid;
    private int _width;
    public int Width { get { return _width; } }
    private int _height;
    public int Height { get { return _height; } }

    private List<Point> _roadList = new List<Point>();
    private List<Point> _specialStructure = new List<Point>();
    private List<Point> _houseStructure = new List<Point>();

    public Grid(int width, int height)
    {
        _width = width;
        _height = height;
        _grid = new CellType[width, height];
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Console.Write("GRID IS RUNNING");
    }

    // Adding index operator to our Grid class so that we can use grid[][] to access specific cell from our grid. 
    public CellType this[int i, int j]
    {
        get
        {
            return _grid[i, j];
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == CellType.Road)
            {
                _roadList.Add(new Point(i, j));
            }
            if (value == CellType.SpecialStructure)
            {
                _specialStructure.Add(new Point(i, j));
            }
            if (value == CellType.Structure)
            {
                _houseStructure.Add(new Point(i, j));
            }
            _grid[i, j] = value;
        }
    }
```

After I initialized it, I called it from another function like this.

```
    public int width, height;
    Grid placementGrid;

    

    private void Start()
    {
        placementGrid = new Grid(width, height);
        Debug.Log(placementGrid.GetRandomRoadPoint());
    }
```

It seems to initialize perfectly. But when I call the functions inside it, I'm returned a null value. I tried calling this function for example:

```
 public Point GetRandomRoadPoint()
    {
        if (_roadList.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return _roadList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, _roadList.Count)];
    }
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I'm basically trying to create a pedestrian AI system for my procedurally generated town.

I tried debugging several times, but I can't seem to find my way around it.

Comment: Well you do `if (_roadList.Count == 0){  return null;   }` and I don't see where you ever add any specific points to your grid .... You just instantite an empty grid with no information stored .... so most probably `_roadList.Count` indeed is `0` ...

Comment: Oh, Right!
Such a silly mistake!

Thanks

Comment: @derHugo any idea why it's returning null/0 ?
I mean besides there not being roads, which there are

Comment: Please include the code that adds CellType's to the grid.  As derHugo mentioned above, there is no place in your code where you assign the data to your grid.